# Weird RecordStore behavior when RecordStoreFullException occurs

Tags: java, java-me, midp, recordstore

I'm developing a small J2ME application that displays bus stops timetables - they are stored as records in MIDP RecordStores.

Sometimes records can not fit a single RecordStore, especially on record update - using setRecord method - a RecordStoreFullException occurs. I catch the exception, and try to write the record to a new RecordStore along with deleting the previous one in the old RecordStore.
Everything works fine except of deleting record from RecordStore where the RecordStoreFullException occurs. If I make an attempt to delete record that could not be updated, another Exception of type InvalidRecordIDException is thrown. This is weird and undocumented in MIDP javadoc. I have tested it on Sun WTK 2.5.2, MicroEdition SDK 3.0 and Nokia Series 40 SDK. Furthermore I created a code that reproduces this strange behaviour:

```
RecordStore rms = null;
        int id = 0;
        try {
            rms  = RecordStore.openRecordStore("Test", true);
            byte[] raw = new byte[192*10024]; //Big enough to cause RecordStoreFullException
            id = rms.addRecord(raw, 0, 160);
            rms.setRecord(id, raw, 0, raw.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                int count = rms.getNumRecords();
                RecordEnumeration en = rms.enumerateRecords(null, null, true);
                count = en.numRecords();
                while(en.hasNextElement()){
                    System.out.println("NextID: "+en.nextRecordId());
                }
                rms.deleteRecord(id); //this won't work!
                rms.setRecord(id, new byte[5], 0, 5); //this won't work too!
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I added extra enumeration code to produce other weird behavior - when RecordStoreFullException occurs, count variable will be set to 1 (if RMS was empty) by both methods - getNumRecords and numRecords. System.out.println will produce NextID: 0! It is not acceptable because record ID can not be 0! 
Could someone explain this strange behavior?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `setRecord` throws `RecordStoreFullException`?

If `addRecord` throws `RecordStoreFullException` then `id` is never updated and you are trying to `deleteRecord(0)`, which could explain the `InvalidRecordIDException`.

The Enumeration code seems to me like it demonstrates a real bug in both Sun and Nokia's implementation of RMS (which could be the same things since Series40 used KVM for a long while). You may be able to pinpoint it (assuming it is still there) by looking at the source code of Sun's implementation at https://phoneme.dev.java.net/

I would advise trying the same on a Series60 phone as it would contain an implementation of RMS developed by Symbian.

Comment: Yes it does. But it depends on emulator/phone You use - on my real Nokia 6233 this behavior occurs - but You must experiment with rawData array length - sometimes it can be too small to cause an exception.

Comment: addRecord can probably never throw an Exception because of small amount of bytes written.

Comment: addRecord *could* be implemented badly enough to throw the exception. it's worth just getting the exception stack trace to make sure.

Comment: I'm sure it is not - the code snippet I provide is only an example - addRecord must be called in order to add at least one record to the store. The setRecord call causes an exception - I checked it, using step by step debugger mode.

Comment: alright. looks like the RMS implementation doesn't fail correctly when it throws the exception. there's still not much you can do beyond checking the source of PhoneME and trying on Series60.